# UINavigationController add UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, parse-framework

[image: Demo Image]

I am creating a app similar to attached image. In this app they uses UITableview with default navigation bar. I am using Parse framework to create app. and i've created a class with **PFQueryTableViewController** as parent class. Now i need to place the fixed bar at top of the table. [shown in image].
when i place a bar it moves up when i scroll table. that means the bar is placed in the particular table cell.
I didn't find how to add view bar just above the table.
So i need help to add view by using parse framework.

Comment: are you looking for `self.tableView.tableHeaderView`?

Comment: I think yes but I need to set the tableHeaderView by using parse framework i.e PFQueryTableViewController

Comment: The reason is PFQueryTableViewController inherits from UITableView hence if you drag a UIToolBar for instance to where you want it, then it shall be in the table header and hence scroll with the table view. The way around this is to use a UIViewController then put the tableview in it and hook up the datasource and delegate methods and also add a UITableView property so you can connect them up.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your navigation bar and fixed bar in the UIVIewController and use the tableview as containerViewController (childviewcontroller). Look here wwdc video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102